# FTP files up to Amazon AWS server

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2

I have not been able to find an answer to this question, although there have been some similar questions. So I have a Amazon EC2 that I launched using a "Magento quick start" on the Amazon marketplace. Anyway so the site is working I can get to it via my domain and can also ssh in.

However when I login via filezilla I am using my key and also the username ubuntu . Now when I try to ftp something into my var/www/magento folder I get a permission denied. The default owner/group is nginx nginx

If I do a

```
    sudo chown -R ubuntu:nginx  var/www/magento
```

I am then able to ftp files up to the server. However when I go in the browser to the url the site then gives me an "this site can not be reached" error in chrome browser. However if I

```
    sudo chown -R nginx:nginx var/www/magento
```

I am then able to see the site in the browser but am back to not being able to upload anything.

I also tried doing

```
   sudo adduser ubuntu nginx
```

I got a success message but still not able to ftp. I get a permission denied error

So what is the ssh command(s) that would enable me to login to sftp with user  ubuntu and be able to upload files and even change file permissions without making the site no longer load when you type in its domain name?

I believe I maybe just need to add the "ubuntu" user to the nginx group?? 
If so what would that command be?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

try `sudo usermod -a -G nginx ubuntu` this will add your existing ubuntu user to nginx group. Also, log out from any existing session and login back.

Comment: Thank you Satish, I logged into ssh and ran the command sudo usermod -a -G nginx ubuntu . I then loged into ftp via filezilla and still was not able to ftp a file up to the directory ??

Comment: i think apart from adding ubuntu user to nginx group, you also need to assign right permission, so any user who belongs to nginx group should be able to upload files. `chmod -R 754 var/www/magento` should do.